# MySQL: what is the best way to create access system?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have table called `page` which represents every single page in my website.

```
page_id | page_subject | page_path
----------------------------------
1       | Foo          | /Foo
2       | Bar          | /Bar
```

I also have table called `group`:

```
group_id | group_name
---------------------
1        | Users
2        | Admins
```

Goal: how to define access to every page for single group?
I did create another table - `page_group`:

```
page_group | group_id
---------------------
1          | 1
1          | 2
```

Table contains groups that have access to page (`page_group`).

I wrote function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `PAGE_ACCESS`(`pageId` INT, `groupId` MEDIUMINT)
BEGIN
   RETURN IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `page_group` WHERE page_id = pageId AND group_id = groupId) > TRUE, FALSE);
END;
```

Now I can do something like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM page 
WHERE <conditions> AND PAGE_ACCESS(page_id, <group_id>)
```

...which returns pages that I should have access to.

Works fine but seems to be slow with with rows > 100,000
How would you do that? Would you do that in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT * 
from Page p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from page_group pg join group g 
              on (pg.group_id = g.groupidId)
              WHERE g.group_id = <groupId>
                AND p.page_id = pg.page_id)
```

Also you can try (just realized that groups table does not required):

```
SELECT * 
from Page p
WHERE p.page_id IN (Select page_id
                    from page_group pg
                    WHERE pg.group_id = <group_id>)
```

or even:

```
SELECT p.* 
from Page p JOIN page_group pg ON (p.page_id = pg.page_id)
WHERE pg.group_id = <group_id>
```

Comment: Surprisingly (to me), this is a very efficient way to do this check - mySQL can optimize this well, if you have good indexes.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

I would test the speed of the query with `EXPLAIN SELECT` - I'm guessing you don't have indexes on the tables? Another speculation: an index on `(page_group.page_group,page_group.group_id)` might speed things up. See [this introduction on EXPLAIN](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm).

In addition, see [@Michael Pakhantsov's answer with the subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511100/mysql-what-is-the-best-way-to-create-access-system/3511134#3511134) - it's easier for the server to optimize a subquery than a UDF.